# Including resource directory from other module in classpath when running from within IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, resources, classpath, project-structure

I have an IntelliJ project with two modules, where `module2` depends on `module1`. Each module has its own resource directory:

**Module 1**

```
module1
    src/
        main/
            resources/
                static/
                    image.png
            ...
    ...
```

**Module 2**

```
module2
    src/
        main/
            resources/
                static/
                    another-image.png
            ...
    ...
```

Using maven to compile `module2` works fine. I'm using the shade plugin and the resulting uber-jar has both resources:

```
static/
    image.png
    another-image.png
```

When *running* the main method from `module2` directly from IntelliJ however, it doesn't seem like `module1/src/main/resources` is on the class path. The project compiles fine, and all `module1`-classes are found when running `module2`. The `module2` resources are also found, but *not* the resources of `module1`. I've tried to add the `module1` resource directory as a content root of `module2`, but I get an error saying

> Module "module2" must not contain source root "module1/src/main/resources".
>   The root already belongs to module "module1"

Comment: What makes you say that "The module2 resources are also found, but not the resources of module1.". Could you post the failing code trying to access `image.png`?

Comment: It's a Wicket application. `<img src="static/another-image.png" />` works, while `<img src="static/image.png" />` doesn't. (Both `image.png` and `another-image.png` shows up in the resulting .jar-file though.)

Comment: This doesn't sound like a Maven problem since the JAR is correct. More like an IntelliJ / Wicket integration fail.

Comment: Yes. I know. This is why I included the intellij-idea tag. (Updated and emphasized that I'm running through the IDE.)